# Some questions on Wi-Fi routers

Tags: wireless-networking

I want to put wi-fi router in  my house.

Can I configure a Wi-fi router with a Dynamic IP or I need Static Ip to use Wi-fi in my house?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some articles that will get you started:

[Beginners Guides: Wireless Home Networking](http://www.pcstats.com/articleview.cfm?articleID=1428)
[4 steps to set up your home wireless network](http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/wirelesssetup.aspx)

Comment: As a highly valued Super User, I suggest you revisit this answer and [add more detail](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users). I also note that link only answers go stale, and editing your answer to reflect some of the information on the sites makes for better, more relevant answers for future users.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: You are of course correct. Except that this post is much too general to merit such an undertaking. My answer really means "learn before asking". I have voted to close this as not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure a router with dynamic IP address. The router will get an external IP address from the modem - which can be static or dynamic, and set up a network with a different range for its clients - which are independent and use one of the three local address blocks.

You will only need a static IP address if you wanted to run a server, and not use dynamic DNS. In your scenario, a dynamic IP address will work with no issues whatsoever.